# Express JS create coffeescript scaffold

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, express, scaffolding

Looking for a way to produce an express scaffold in coffeescript straight off the bat.

At the moment `$ express 'myapp'` just creates js files.

Any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transform the created app.js and routes/index.js files into coffeescript using js2coffee (like Slace stated) 
There are two ways:
1. Manually using the [js2coffee.org converter](http://js2coffee.org/)

2. Using the `js2coffee` npm package and piping the output into a new file

```
$ cd my_new_express_app
$ sudo npm install js2coffee -g
Files can now be converted by running js2coffee input.js > output.coffee 
$ js2coffee app.js > app.coffee
$ js2coffee routes/index.js > routes/index.coffee
```

This way you can start a fresh express project in coffeescript. Note that the conversion strips comments away.

Answer (score 1):

Express only generates JavaScript from the scaffolding. You can use [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/) to do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

After generating your express app and installing js2coffee, as previously mentioned, change directory to your new app and run:

```
for f in `find . -type f -path "*.js" ! -path "*node_modules*"`; js2coffee $f > "${f%.*}.coffee"
```